# Illustrator: how to crop image without losing quality

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, crop

I'm trying to use Illustrator to edit .eps images.

[image]

I want to crop an image. But it always decreases the resolution of the image after whatever way I crop it.

[image]

I tried setting the cropping resolution to 300dpi or Original, but neither worked.
There doesn't seem to be a working solution online.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain your process and/or post screencaps so we know what's going on?

Comment: @GerardFalla just added screenshots for before and after. As you can see the image becomes blurred after cropping

Comment: Is that a raster image?  If so, then why are you using Illustrator?  Vector graphics have no resolution.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are right. It turned out that that .eps file was not vectorized at all!!!

Comment: The best way to 'crop' a raster image in Illustrator would be to apply a clipping mask to it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I figured out a way:
Enlarge the image in Illustrator, crop, and then drag the corner to resize the image back to the desired size.

It seems that Illustrator compresses small images after cropping but is more tolerating for bigger images

Comment: The answer is really to use a raster image editor if you need to crop a raster image.